# How to edit the style for a Cancel Button in Sencha Framework.

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have this code

I need apply a theme to a Cacel Button present in a DataPicker... any idea how to make it?

{
                xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                label: 'Start Date XXX',
                name: 'DateStart',

```
            //labelWidth: labelWidth,
            value: new Date(),
            picker: {
                yearFrom: yearFrom,
                yearTo  : yearTo,
                hideOnMaskTap: true




            //                toolbar: {
            //                    xtype: 'toolbar',
            //                    items: [
            //                        {
            //                            /*xtype: 'button',
            //                            text: 'Left',*/
            //                            ui: 'custom-btn-confirm',
            //                            style: 'color: #ffffff'
            //                        },
            //                        {
            //                            /*xtype: 'button',
            //                            text: 'Left Two',*/
            //                            ui: 'custom-btn-confirm',
            //                            style: 'color: #ffffff'
            //                        }
            //                    ]
            //                }                





            }                          
        },                                   
        {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write custom CSS for the button by using: `cls: 'myapp-cancelbutton'` or you can use the predefined `ui: 'cancel'`